# Gmail CC(copy) like implementation

Tags: php, sql

Hello guys I am working on a simple E-memo web application. Every part is set except the copy CC part. While sending memo, the user is allowed to copy another user. Only the memo receiver (target) and those copied can see the memo.

```php
// CONNECTION TO DB AND SELECT user's office FROM DB
include 'extradbcon.php';

echo ' <div class="form-group"><label class="small mb-1">Memo CC</label><select  name="Memocopy[]"class="form-control " id="copy" multiple> <option value=""> Select</option><option value="All"> All</option>';

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    unset($Value, $Title);
    $Value = $row['Office'];
    $Title = $row['Office'];
    // echo '<option value="">Select</option>';
    echo '<option value="'.$Value.'">'.$Title.'</option>';
}

echo "</select>";
echo "</div>";
//echo "</html>"
```

The code above populates the select from database and allows multiple select. I get I have to set post as an array. I am to save the values in table, column named `copy`. To display memo to copied users I am using the where clause

```php
$sql = "SELECT * FROM memotbl WHERE copy = $useroffice";
```

so users will only see memos where they are copied.

Problem now is in `copy` column, all copied office are saved in the column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simple wildcard %''% solved the problem .Lolz

```
<?php 
$sql = "SELECT * from  memotbl  WHERE  copy1  LIKE '%{$useroffice}%'";?>
```